# SpringBoot and JUnit - Testing Service class - Failed to load Application Context

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to run a unit test on a service class in a Spring Boot Application

i would like to try this test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class) //my @SpringBootApplication class
public class UserServiceTest { //i'm testing my UserService implementation

    @TestConfiguration
    static class UserServiceContextConfiguration {


        @Bean
        public IUserService service() {
            return new UserService();
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    private IUserService service;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        User me = new User();

        me.setEmail("admin@admin.com");

        Mockito.when(repository.findByEmail(me.getEmail())).thenReturn(me);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenValidEmail_thenFindUser() {
        String email = "admin@admin.com";
        User found = service.findByEmail(email);

        assertThat(found.getEmail()).isEqualTo(email);
    }

}
```

But when launching the test i get this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.myapp.service.UserServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.service.interfaces.IUserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Maybe it is not clear to me but `@TestConfiguration` should allow me to define my beans from the application to use them in the tests and @SpringBootTest should load all the application context from the app for the test environment...

Answer (score 2):

By providing `classes=Application.class` you turned off automatic scanning of inner configuration classes.

Either remove the explicit classes parameter - SpringRunner will search for SpringBootApplication annotated class in current packages and parent packages and also search for inner configuration classes,

or add this to your @SpringBootTest

```
@SpringBootTest(classes= {Application.class, UserServiceContextConfiguration.class })
```